# How to use Nuget.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstaller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am looking everywhere and nothing works, nor is it complete enough to use.

I want to dynamically install packages from a Custom Template.  I have already used the  element of the vsTemplate file, but I would like to be able to use the NuGet API to do it more dynamically.

This is my set up, and for now it HAS to stay this way.

- Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise
- EnvDTE (8.0.1)
- EnvDTE80 (8.0.1)
- Nuget.VisualStudio (5.11.3)
- VSLangProj (7.0.3300)

With that, I have the following methods on the IWizard

```
public DTE2 Application {get;set;}
public Project Project { get; private set; }

public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
{
   this.Application = (DTE2)automoationObject;
}

public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem projectItem)
{
  this.Project = projectItem?.ContainingProject;
}

public void RunFinished() 
{
    IVsPackageInstaller installer;
    
    //Get Nuget Package Installer

    installer.InstallPackage(null, this.Project, "MyCustomPackage", "1.0.0", false);
}
```

Where i put "get nuget package installer" what do i put in there?
Everywhere i search i get this "GetService" but not where that method lives, or how to access it, at the Nuget.VisualStudio version 5.11.3.  I Cannot update to later versions at this time, but so far every suggestion I find on the net doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From some public projects using this, I found them Call GetService() from the IComponentModel, just like this:

```
using System;

namespace FrameworkInstallPackage
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost;
    using NuGet.VisualStudio;
    using TPL = System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
    using EnvDTE;

    internal interface IPackageHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the VS package
        /// </summary>
        AsyncPackage Package { get; } //the root class AsyncPackage comes from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the function
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="project">The project to peform actions on</param>
        /// <returns>A task that executes the function</returns>
        TPL.Task Execute(Project project);
    }
    internal abstract class BasePackageHandler : IPackageHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BasePackageHandler"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="successor">The successor</param>
        protected BasePackageHandler(IPackageHandler successor)
        {
            this.Successor = successor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(successor));
            if (successor.Package == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("successor.Package must not be null");
            }

            this.Package = this.Successor.Package;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the VS package
        /// </summary>
        public AsyncPackage Package { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the successor handler
        /// </summary>
        protected IPackageHandler Successor { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public abstract TPL.Task Execute(Project project);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Installs the latest SlowCheetah NuGet package
    /// </summary>
    internal class NugetInstaller : BasePackageHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NugetInstaller"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="successor">The successor with the same package</param>
        public NugetInstaller(IPackageHandler successor)
            : base(successor)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public override async TPL.Task Execute(Project project)
        {
            var componentModel = (IComponentModel)await this.Package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(SComponentModel));
            IVsPackageInstaller packageInstaller = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost as it requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop, which conflicts with EnvDTE.  (ProjectItem exists in both assemblies)

Comment: Okay - so I am fully able to test this now, but there is no connection between the "automationObject" (as a DTE2) into something that can grab the IComponentModel for getting the IVsPackageInstaller service.  How do i go from an Microsoft IWizard to the Nuget IVsPackageInstaller?