# How do I get IVsPackageInstaller in Template Wizard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have vstemplates, and a template wizard.  in the WizardStarted implementation of IWizard there is the AutomationObject provided by Visual Studio.
From there all of the suggestions mention getting the Nuget.VisualStudio IVsPackageInstaller from an IComponentModel.GetService call, but i can't find out how to get the IComponentModel reference.
In my wizard i have tried casting the automationObject as an IComponentModel but it doesn't cast.  So where/how do I connect the IWizard implementation (automationObject) to the IVsPackageInstaller to install nuget packages dynamically?

Edit:
(here is base code for the IWizard found in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard assembly)

```
public class MyWizard : IWizard
{
    public DTE Application { get; private set; }

    public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {
        this.Application = automationObject as DTE;
        replacementsDictionary["$safeitemname$"] = "newitemcode.cs";
    }

    public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
    {
        /* n/a for item generation */
    }

    public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem projectItem)
    {
        IVsSolution sol = this.Application.Solution as IVsSolution;
        if (sol != null)
        {
            InstallNugetPackages();
        }
    }

    private void InstallNugetPackages()
    {
        IComponentModel host = this.Application as IComponentModel; //<-- does not work.  host is null;
        IVsPackageInstaller installer = host.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller>();
    }

    public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RunFinished()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

other links:
[Wizards (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022)
[My Other Question on how to Nuget Package Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75197875/how-to-use-nuget-visualstudio-ivspackageinstaller)

Comment: I can't find any code samples for what a wizard actually looks like, what services and interfaces it has access to. Can you either provide a minimal "hello world" wizard, or at least a link to a working wizard, so we can see what's available?

Comment: Actually, I just remembered a major problem with trying to invoke NuGet APIs in the wizard is that the project hasn't been initialized via IVsSolution yet, so NuGet will fail, not knowing that the project exists.  For SDK style .NET projects, the whole project initialization is async (to make solution load faster), and you need to wait longer until the project system has told NuGet that the project exists. This can be done with the [operation progress API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.operationprogress?view=visualstudiosdk-2022), I believe.